# Spanish protection of data obey. Question about a possible Sue against your company

Tags: user-interface

I am really worried about the Spanish law of data protection. I would like to know if you have applied a special  plan to obey this law.
Thank you

Comment: It would probably help if you explain to us what the Spanish law is? Otherwise I find it extremely hard to answer :-). Also, can you explain who the 'you' is you address in your question? As you know CiviCRM is open source software developed and maintained by a community, not by a single entity like a company.

Comment: Is this more to do with hosting than with code?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the same as the EU data protection directive?  The good news is that it doesn't go in to force until mid-2018, so you've got a bit of time to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more about hosting and configuration of your infrastructure than about the functionality of CiviCRM?